# Adding terminal commands to MonoDevelop each time build is hit

Tags: macos, terminal, automation, monodevelop

Is it possible to have MonoDevelop also run a certain terminal command each time that you hit build?

For example, I'd like to have document generation automatically generated each time I build my project in MonoDevelop. I usually do this by having to run a terminal command `NaturalDocs -i inputFolder -O OutputFolder -p ProjDirectory`